# When activating DATA, all Apps wants to go online at the same time. any fix?

Tags: cyanogenmod, wi-fi, mobile-data, system-freeze, cpu

I like to deactivate my 4G Data or Wifi when I'm not using it.

But whenever I activate Data (4G or Wifi), all the Cores of the CPU are being used at 100% and the phone becomes unusable for at least 30sec.

So it seems that All the APPS wants to go online at the same time, rather than one by one.

It's very annoying when I just want to go online for the GPS or the Browser : I have to wait 30sec minimum every time.

[Phone : Samsung S3 I9300 with Cyanogenmod]

Comment: Maybe Greenify?

Comment: How many apps do you have? Which CyanogenMod version are we talking about? What app are you using to see info concerning the CPU?

Comment: micro CPU monitor. CyanogenMod 11 (4.4.4), 34 apps. I block half of them via a firewall (droidwall) but even with or without it, I have the same issue.